# Classloader Error while attempting to create Account object

Tags: salesforce

When attempting to execute the line `Account a = new Account();` I receive the error

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at merchantapp.MerchantAPP.main(MerchantAPP.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.ws.bind.XMLizable
ay java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 25 more
Java Result: 1
```

While it looks like the error is being caused by my program not being able to find the class XMLizable, I am unable to execute `import com.sforce.ws.*;` which would import the needed class.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the jar file created using `java -classpath wsc-23.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc SFwsdl.xml salesforce.jar` was not including all of the necessary packages into salesforce.jar. This was stopping me from being able to include `import com.sforce.ws.*;` in my code.

To fix this, I imported the wsc-23.jar file provided from `https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/downloads/list` into my project as well. Once I did so, I was able to import all of the packages and use any of the objects that were hidden from me before.

If any one comes across a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.